# convert variable to const

Tags: c++, boost, constants

I have an array that i dont know it size till run time. Once the program starts and size is computed, the size won't change.

i tested the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{

    uint32_t num_bits = 12;
    const uint32_t num_elements = 1 << num_bits;

    boost::array<double, num_elements > myArray; //does not work

    return 0;

}
```

the following code doesn't work since `num_elements` is computed. I saw that there are "const_cast" option, but i am not sure if it will solve my problem.

I would apprichiate if there is a boost solution, since i would like to use boost::array.

**EDIT**
`num_bits` is a parameter which i read from a file, this mean also unknown before run time. I am aware of the solution using std::vector, but access speed is also important, since i access those elements frequently and my simulation takes about 3 days... At the moment i use simply array (new and delete)

Comment: you can't put arrays with a dynamic size on the stack. You could either use `array<double,(1<<12)>` edit: nvm boost::array can't be dynamic in size

Comment: @PeterT `alloca` is dynamic stack allocation. Most compilers also support C99-style VLAs.

Comment: `std::vector` is generally as fast, if not faster than `new`/`delete`. (It can be faster when the library implementation and the compiler optimizer work together to eliminate aliasing, but this is very rarely significant.)

Answer (score 4):

Boost array is for arrays whose size is known at compile time. Its arguments have to be constant expressions.

Use std::vector or similar container.

Although your example doesn't need to be calculated at run time:

```
const uint32_t num_bits = 12; // mark this const too
const uint32_t num_elements = 1 << num_bits;

boost::array<double, num_elements > myArray;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately num_bits is also not known before run-time

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Formally, template arguments have to be _Integral Constant Expressions_. Informally, that means expressions that the compiler can compute. That explains why `const_cast` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use `std::vector` instead of `boost::array`? The size of a `std::vector` can be computed at runtime.

The `const_cast` only converts a variable to/from `const` at runtime as well, it can't be used to create a constant at compile-time, which `boost::array` (and the new C++11 `std::array`) wants.

Answer (score 0):

Argument to any `template` should be a compile time constant (or type). If you know `num_bits` at compile time then use it as compile time constant:

```
boost::array<double, (1 << num_bits)> myArray; //ok
```

If the size is not known at compile time then use dynamically allocated arrays  or `std::vector`.